# Recovering representation of finite group from associated adjoint representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a group and assume $G$ finite for simplicity. Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let $\rho: G \to \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ be a representation of $G$. To $\rho$ we can associate another representation $\operatorname{ad}(\rho): G \to \operatorname{GL}(\operatorname{M}_n(k))$ defined by $g \mapsto (A \mapsto \rho(g)A\rho(g)^{-1})$.

How much does $\operatorname{ad}(\rho)$ know about $\rho$? Clearly, if $\rho(g)$ lies in the centre $Z$ of $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ then $\operatorname{ad}(\rho)(g) = 1$. Can we recover $\overline \rho: G \to \operatorname{GL}_n(k)/Z$ from $\operatorname{ad}(\rho)$?

We can assume that $k$ is algebraically closed, if it makes a difference. Apologies if this is a well-known result.

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{GL}_n(k))$ doesn't make sense, as $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ is not a vector space. You probably mean $\mathrm{GL}(M_{n\times n}(k))$ instead.

Comment: @LukasHeger You're right, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: In the language of modules, also without choosing bases, you are asking for a $k[G]$-module $V$ if the $k[G]$-module $\mathrm{End}_k(V)$ tells us anything about $V$.

Comment: Do you want $\rho$ to be irreducible? In the language of characters, you are asking whether $\overline\rho$ can be recovered from the absolute value of the characters $|\chi_\rho(g)|,g\in G$. Of course, you could only hope to recover $\{\overline\rho,\overline\rho^\vee\}$. So the question (I think) should be: if $\rho,\tau$ are irreducible representations such that $|\chi_\rho(g)|=|\chi_\tau(g)|$ then $\overline\rho\simeq\overline\tau$ or $\overline\rho\simeq\overline\tau^\vee$.